# Set TLS connection settings for Bouncy Castle TLS server

Tags: java, bouncycastle, tls1.2

I'm currently working on a demo TLS server using Bouncy Castle (bctls-jdk15on v1.64). So far I was able to get a working example with Bouncy Castle's default settings for TLS. The `TlsServer` I use looks as follows

```
var tlsServer = new DefaultTlsServer(encryptor)
{
    protected TlsCredentialedSigner getRSASignerCredentials() throws IOException {
         var keyParams = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
         var encryptionParams = new TlsCryptoParameters(context);

         return new BcDefaultTlsCredentialedSigner(
              encryptionParams,
              (BcTlsCrypto) encryptor,
              keyParams, 
              certificate,
              SignatureAndHashAlgorithm.rsa_pss_rsae_sha256
         );
    }
};
```

Now I would like to set the maximum plaintext fragment length ([RFC6066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-4)) and the offered cipher suites. Bouncy Castle's documentation [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/tlsdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/tls/DefaultTlsServer.html) does not provide sufficient guidance.

How could I set these parameters in the code above?